# php conditional if (is_page('category/*'))

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a conditional statement where if it is a certain page, but what if I want it to be a certain page with anything after it? I tried using a wild card, but that doesn't seem to work... It doesn't give me an error though...

```
<?php if (is_page('category/*')) : ?>
```

Comment: Do you know what column do here?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php if (is_page('category/')) : ?>
```

or this

```
<?php if (is_page('category')) : ?>
```

You may just be able to check a directory.